# xcopy all files from a UNC path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to copy multiple files from a UNC path if a certain file does not exist in the destination directory.

```
SET DEST=\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\FolderName
if not exist "%DEST%\sqlpackage.exe" (xcopy "%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries\*.*" "%DEST%" /S /V /I /R /Y)
```

`%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries\` exists and does contain files I needed.
But I got
`File not found - *.*`
`0 File(s) copied`

I also tried

```
SET DEST=\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\FolderName
if not exist "%DEST%\sqlpackage.exe" (xcopy "%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries\" "%DEST%" /S /V /I /R /Y)

SET DEST=\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\FolderName
if not exist "%DEST%\sqlpackage.exe" (xcopy "%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries" "%DEST%" /S /V /I /R /Y)

SET DEST="\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\FolderName"
if not exist "%DEST%\sqlpackage.exe" (xcopy "%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries\*.*" "%DEST%" /S /V /I /R /Y)
```

But none of above works. I think it has something to do with the UNC but don't know what would be the correct syntax.

So it's kind of stupid that my major problem actually is the source should not be `%DEST%\SqlPackageBinaries\` but `\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\SqlPackageBinaries\`.
And to be honest, I copy the command from another section of the code and modified the content that I didn't really look into the meaning of each parameter like `/S` as you mention. I simply assume that would be something like do not prompt or overwrite if the file exists.

Comment: You try to copy the whole tree (`/S`) of a sub-directory into its parent directory; are there any conflicts? what is the error message?

Comment: Thanks for all replies/explanations, I'm not familiar with the batch script, I will try `robocopy`

Answer (score 2):

Always enclose your `set` command variable and value in double quotes, as in my example. Then, although `xcopy` is still available on windows devices, it has been deprecated. Use `robocopy` instead:

```
@echo off
set "dest=\\ServerName\TestReleases\My Database\FolderName"
if exist "%dest%\sqlpackage.exe" goto :EOF
robocopy "%dest%\SqlPackageBinaries" "%dest%"
```